# Ubuntu 14.04 / Unity- onboard utility (on-screen keyboard) - desktop icon

Tags: unity, icons, onboard

I would like to have some easier way to launch "onboard" (on-screen keyboard utility).

Once onboard is launched it conveniently sits on a service bar (would be nice to have some improvements there too) but before it is activated one needs to search for it in installed applications every time ubuntu is started.

I would like to place onboard launcher on the desktop (as it never appears in launcher bar so onboard cannot be locked to it)

I have tried various recipes (including making symbolic links) but none is working for me.

Is it somehow possible to create a desktop icon to start onboard when it is not started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Find "On Board" Desktop file form following location:

`/usr/share/applications/`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/onboard.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Onboard
GenericName=Onboard onscreen keyboard
Comment=Flexible onscreen keyboard for GNOME
Exec=onboard
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Accessibility;
#NotShowIn=GNOME;
#NotShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=false
MimeType=application/x-onboard;
Icon=onboard
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=onboard
```

**Drag It to Launcher!**

[image]

Comment: following this recipe I also tried `~/Desktop$ ln -s /usr/share/applications/onboard.desktop onboard.desktop` and that worked too.